# Install script needs to set up a program to run on login in Linux

Tags: linux, installation, gnome, kde-plasma

I need to write an install script that runs an executable/script on login (not startup) in Linux. This needs to work for all current users who can log into the system and users created in the future as well. Is there a way to do this?

In windows this can be achieved by putting a shortcut in the startup folder for "All Users". Is there a similar location/init script in Linux? If not, are there any alternatives?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The question isn't about programming, but good suited on the Unix & Linux site of SE.

Answer (score 1):

The users ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile depending on shell is executed at login.  You can add to that.  If you want it for every user, you could put it in /etc/profile.